# How to import an Excel file with dynamic worksheet name ? (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import, worksheet

I basically set a procedure that imports from Excel to SQL in T-SQL:

```
SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\report.xls','select * from [name555$]')
```

The name555 consists of a fixed name, and the 555 from what appears to be a random three digits number. When the report comes to me, sometimes the name is 555, sometimes it's 439, 390 etc.

Is there a way to instruct SQL server (preferrably in T-SQL as that's what I'm using right now) to read the name dynamically? It's the only sheet in the XLS file but it

For example in VBA you can use the sheet as a name1$ name or as a "sheet1$" index. Well, I hope somebody can help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can query the SCHEMA of the workbook to retrieve the TABLE (worksheet) names.  If you only have one worksheet in your workbook, the first valid TABLE_NAME is going to be the name of your worksheet.

Given below (in VB.NET code) is a helper method that I use all the time for this kind of task.  The return value of the function places the brackets around the name for you, so it's ready to use in a SQL statement.

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns the name of the first worksheet in an Excel workbook.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="connectString">OleDb connection string for an Excel workbook.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function GetTableName(ByVal connectString As String) As String

  Dim dtSheets As New DataTable
  Dim tmp As String = ""

  Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connectString)
     cn.Open()
     dtSheets = cn.GetSchema("Tables")
  End Using

  For Each rw As DataRow In dtSheets.Rows
     'Get the name of the first worksheet in the file that ends
     'with a $.
     tmp = rw("TABLE_NAME")
     'Check to see if the table name is surrounded by apostorphes.
     If tmp.StartsWith("'") And tmp.EndsWith("'") Then
        'Remove the apostrophes.
        tmp = tmp.TrimEnd("'")
        tmp = tmp.TrimStart("'")
     End If

     If tmp.EndsWith("$") Then
        Exit For
     Else
        tmp = ""
     End If
  Next

  Return "[" & tmp & "]"

End Function
```